# Running gedit using WSL2 and VcXsrv

Tags: wsl2, ubuntu-22.04, vcxsrv

I have managed to configure Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL2 and I have working VcXsrv. I have verified it by running sample application ***xeyes*** and also ***vlc*** and I can confirm that it is running using VcXsrv wihtout any issues. However I am unable to run ***gedit*** in this way, ***gedit*** appears to be running some kind of native linux window. When I check VcXsrv clients there are none unlike with xyeyes for example where I can see a client as soon as I run the application.

What desktop is it using? Is there a way to make it run using XServer instead?

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  I'm curious why you are attempting to use VcXsrv for this?  Most WSL2 installations should [support GUI applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) out-of-the-box using WSLg.  It's possible that you have both WSLg (which supports Wayland) and that your VcXsrv configuration is interfering with it.

Comment: Hello @NotTheDr01ds thank you, first of, it's good to know that it is called WSLg for further search. My issue with it, I suppose gedit is also running through WSLg, is that it does not support standard windows behavior such as dragging to the top for full resolution and such. With for example VLC that runs through VcXsrv I have no such issue.

Comment: Ah, that's a completely fair point and is certainly a limitation of WSLg.